# RxJS - query server every 3 seconds for 15 seconds or positive result

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I want to query server every 3 seconds until I receive positive return or 15 seconds passes. Here is code I have, but it doesn't work:

**service.ts**

```
getStatus(id: number): Observable<Status> {
    return 
        from(this.webSvc.getStatus(id))
            .pipe(
                 throttleTime(3000),
                 mergeMap((result: Status) => {
                     if (result.IsProcessed) {
                          return of(result);
                     }

                     return throwError(null);
                 }),
                 retry(5) // I assume, that 5 retries * 3sec throttle time = 15 seconds
           );
}
```

**controller.ts**

```
service.getStatus(item.id)
    .subscribe(
        (status: Status) => {
            // some logic
        },
        error => {
            // error logic
        }
    );
```

Comment: Do you want to start a new request every three seconds or wait three seconds between response and the next request?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do the following:

```
defer(() => yourRequest()).pipe(
  retryWhen(obs$ => obs$.pipe(delay(3000))),
  timeout(15000)
);
```

Here's a live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ssanxj?file=index.ts

To explain a bit what's going on:

- It'll make a request straight away and wait for either an answer or an error
- in case of an error, it'll wait 3s, and retry the request
- if things keep failing, after 15s a timeout will throw an error
- as soon as things go well, we'll receive the response and stop the polling

Comment: How then can you include condition (if is processed ...) as I have presented?

Comment: If it's processed, then you can just do something after the whole stream :) otherwise there'll be an error

Comment: But then, why should I keep asking server when I know my item was processed? For example, if my server is super fast, my item will be processed after 10ms. I ask for status and get IsPRocessed = true. There is no point asking for 12 more seconds, because I know the status already.

Comment: It won't :) I've made a stackblitz to demo. Please take a look

Comment: I've also added an explanation